# Import var from js file in Typescripts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

For context (though it's not that important), I'm trying to import SVGMorpheus into a typescript project (Angular 2).

SVGMorpheus is just a global. It's declared like so:

```
var SVGMorpheus = (function(){....code...})())
```

i.e. standard old-school javascript IIFE assigned to a global. In my project I'm trying to import it as such:

`import * as SVGMorpheus from "./path/to/svg-morpheus"`

This works fine and gives no error, but SVGMorpheus is then just an empty object.

`console.log(SVGMorpheus); //Outputs "{}"`.

Any attempt to use it causes errors.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've also added a typings.d.ts file which doesn't help. SVGMorpheus doesn't have support for typings or any sort of UMD form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an angular-cli problem. I hadn't registered the script with the compiler.
Adding the node_module to the scripts array in the app object inside the angular-cli.json file did the trick:

```
{
   ...
   "apps": [
      ...app definition stuff...
      "scripts": [
          "path/to/external/module"
      ]   
   ]
}
```

Note this should work for any external IIFE-type import. No other code updates were required (the original post code works).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a special problem from Typesciprt, but general problem that can happen in all cases in which files are to be imported/exported. The answer is that not all javascript files are ready to be exported. Especially, in this case, the answer is "No". I am going to assume that you are using Webpack, and if you don't I strongly recommend you to use Webpack eventually.

From the official document written by Webpack guys (https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules), there is a way to resolve this case, in which the files are not supporting the modern technologies of import/export.

You need "exports-loader" to make your IIFE global module to be ready for exporting to other scripts.

```
var SVGMorpheus = require('./path/to/svg-morpheus'); // Wrong
var SVGMorpheus = require('exports-loader?SVGMorpheus!./path/to/svg-morpheus'); // Good
```

Hope this answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: Close, turns out I hadn't included it in the script section in the angular-cli file. My answer explains.